# How to get the JSON on url the DJANGO REST API framework?

Tags: python, json, django, api

How to display the result  json at URL

```
https://api.vk.com/method/friends.get?user_id=2183659&count=10&fields=nickname,photo_100
```

As in the picture:

[image]

I can easily do this in PHP, just create a new PHP file and write:

```
 <?php 
    $url = 'https://api.vk.com/method/friends.get?user_id=2183659&count=10&fields=nickname,photo_100'; 
    $content = file_get_contents($url); 
    $json = json_decode($content, true);


    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($json['response']);
    echo "</pre>"; 
 ?>
```

Result:
[image]

**But I do not know how to do this in the Django interface.**

*P.S. Google Translate.
Why do you put a minus? I can explain to you more clearly what I need in Russian. :)*

Comment: Not sure what you mean? You want `pprint`? Or you want the exact same template html as DRF admin uses

Comment: @jamylak I have a task, to output the result of JSON at URL in the interface API DJANGO how to do it?  sorry my english, google translate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i understaand, just set up an `APIView` `get(...)` and return `Reponse(json)` where `json = requests.get("https://api.vk.com/method/friends.get?user_id=2183659&count=10&fields=nickname,photo_100").json()`

Comment: $url = '';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);  It's on php, how to do it on the interface DJANGO REST

Comment: I'm beginner in this, so I need to explain what and where I shoud insert

Comment: I gave you steps to research, you may need to read some tutorials on DRF

Comment: I came to the right decision on APIView, thank you for that.